# Use word2vec in tokenized sentences

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word-embedding

I am trying to create a emotion recognition model resorting to SVM. I have a big dataset of sentences each one with a labeled emotion. After text pre-processing, I have a pandas data frame containing the tokenized sentences, like it can be seen in [1.] [image: Dataframe adter pre-processing].

My objective is to turn all this tokenized sentences to word embeddings so that I can train models such as SVM. The problem is how to use this date frame as input to word2vec or any other word embedding model.

Comment: Do you have the complete sentence? Is there any particular reason for not using `transformers`? Why don't you exploit popular methods like averaging word vectors throughout an entire sentence?

Comment: First I would like to start with svm and naive bayes maybe, the I will try the transformers. What do you mean by the last question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one vector per input instance if you want to use SVM. This means that you need to get embeddings for the words and do some operation, typically pooling, that will shrink the sequence of word embeddings into a single vector.

The most frequently used methods are mean-pooling and max-pooling, simply taking the average or the maximum of the embeddings.

Assuming, you pandas data frames in variable `data` and you have the word embeddings in a dictionary `embedding_table` with string keys and NumPy array value, you can do something like this (mean pooling), assuming that at least one word is covered by the word embeddings:

```py
def embed(word_sequence):
    embeddings = []
    for word in word_sequence:
        if word in embedding_table:
            embeddings.append(word)
    return np.mean(embeddings, axis=0)

data["vector"] = data.Utterance.map(embed)
```

Comment: Basically, that code will transform any sentence into a svm input right?

Comment: It transforms any list of words where at least one word is in the embedding table into a vector that can be used in a classifier (SVM, logistic regression, simple feedforward neural net).